# Perform a single WMI query to multiple classes, it is possibly?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, wmi

I need to perform various queries to different WMI classes, then instead of doing query one by one, to improve the speed of execution I thinked in this:

In C# or else VB.Net, I would like to know whether a single query can be done to retrieve the properties of multiple classes at once.

Random not functional example:

```
Using wmi As New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(
    "select SerialNumber from Win32_BaseBoard, select Caption from Win32_Process"
)

...

End Using
```

If yes, which is the proper query syntax?

Comment: The answer to your question is probably *no*: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What makes you think the combined query wouldnt simply take 2ce as long?

Comment: @Plutonix, I made some time measures of the Win32_Process execution time compared to the Process class (GetProcesses), but you can see this everywhere, I always heard that WMI takes so long in difference to other ways to retrieve the same info (under .Net class library) and I also did my measures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this, using NET 4.5:

```vb
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Collections.Concurrent
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Dim wql As String() = {"SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_BaseBoard",
                               "SELECT Name FROM Win32_BIOS",
                               "SELECT VideoProcessor FROM Win32_VideoController",
                               "SELECT RegisteredUser FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"}

Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)
For Each q In wql
    Dim t As task = Task.Run(Sub()
                                 Dim str = WMI.GetWMIClassProperty(q)
                                 wList.Add(str)
                             End Sub
    )
    tasks.Add(t)
Next

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray)
```

This is the NET 4.0 version:

```vb
Dim wmiAction As Action(Of Object) = Sub(s As Object)
                                         Dim str = WMI.GetWMIClassProperty(s.ToString)
                                         wList.Add(str)
                                     End Sub

Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)
For Each q In wql
    Dim t As New task(wmiAction, q)
    tasks.Add(t)
    t.Start()
Next

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray)
```

`WMI.GetWMIClassProperty` just creates a searcher for the query and returns the first property or `String.Empty`.

Using a `Stopwatch` it takes 72-80ms to run the 4 in succession, 15-20ms to run them as Tasks (NET 4 ver is 2-3ms slower).  Almost as fast (18-25ms) is a `Parrallel.ForEach` but seems a but less involved and also works with NET 4.0:

```vb
Parallel.ForEach(wql, Sub(thisQ)
                          Dim str = WMI.GetWMIClassProperty(thisQ)
                          wList.Add(str)
                      End Sub)
```

All four methods return the same results in `wList`, though in differing orders, so you'd want a way to qualify which results are which.  The differences do increase if you query some of the truly slow WMI classes.

Comment: is not a single query at all but the asynchronous approach is very nice, thankyou as always @Plutonix.